# Change image in a UIImageView in a different class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have two views, One is the Gameview and the other and a menu where I would like the user to select a button and it will change the image view in GameView to that image.

I has this bit of code for doing this but It doesn't seem to be working...

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"goToGameViewsSegue"]) {
        MainMenuView_4inch_White *dest = [segue destinationViewController];
        dest.imageView = CloudyBlue; //set the image in your view as the image in the settings view
        [dest.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cloudy-Eye-Blue.png"]];
        NSLog(@"Image should have been changed here.. How come it didn't?");

    }
}
```

I did check over all of the connection and if the segues was connected and it is all good so mustn't be that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're changing the `UIImageView` object in the destination view controller, you need to make sure it's added as a subview to the correct superview.

```
 dest.imageView = CloudyBlue; 
 [dest.view addSubview:CloudyBlue]; // add it to the correct view and set the frame, depending on what you need.
```

---

But for the sake of keeping your code clean and modular, I recommend doing this kind of thing inside the destination view controller. Having one view controller mess with another's views is error prone and I don't recommend it.

For example, you could have this in your destination view controller:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image 
{
     // 1) set up self.imageView, if necessary

     // 2) set the image
     self.imageView.image = image;     
}
```

Comment: How can I set the frame of the image of the gameview?

Comment: You do it just like you would for any `UIView`, e.g. `myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);`

See also the edit I made to my answer about the best place to do these things.